# Distribution of "tags" on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags

I wonder how does the tags distribution look like.

Comment: What are you actually asking here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then look at the tags page:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Comment: heh, that might actually be what he's looking for :D

Comment: He might want a graph. @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: Somehting like this? http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/#!c+java+c%23+javascript+scala+erlang+haskell+go+ada

Comment: That's pretty sweet :D Can that result be embedded in a answer without making a screenshot out of it?

Comment: No idea ask [Greg](http://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) he made it.

Comment: [I added the most popular tags in the graph](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/#!java+javascript+c%23+php+android+jquery+python+html+c%2B%2B+mysql+ios+css+sql+asp.net+objective-c)

Comment: damn - I missed it :)